# Google maps directions failing saddr daddr

Tags: google-maps

I am sending directions in emails with this syntax

https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=58.2835809,12.269723200000044&daddr=58.03126090000001,12.803917500000011+to:58.03126090000001,12.803917500000011+to:58.2583346,12.95071710000002+to:58.2835809,12.269723200000044

This has stopped to work in Android and iPhone but still works in desktop browsers. I have tried to find a solution on the web but failed to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: which bit of it's stopped working?  Do you see the map, but no directions? Are the directions wrong?  Does no map appear at all?

Comment: The map app loads. With an exclamation mark and the text "No results for" and a coordinate list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with this syntax:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/58.2835809,12.269723200000044/58.03126090000001,12.803917500000011/58.2583346,12.95071710000002/58.2835809,12.269723200000044/am=t

Answer (score 2):

That is the "classic" Google Maps directions, it was never documented (by Google).  You can use the documented [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode):

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions
  ?key=YOUR_API_KEY
  &origin=58.2835809,12.269723200000044
  &destination=58.03126090000001,12.80391750000001
  &waypoints=58.03126090000001,12.803917500000011|58.2583346,12.95071710000002|58.2835809,12.269723200000044
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_directions_waypoints.html)